# Increase thumb sensitivity of object on canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an object on canvas which user can select and move ... using two thumbs around it. My question is that how can I increase sensitivity of mouse such that when cursor gets close to thumb allow user to drag/move the object?

Of course it is not the mouser sensitivity but I believe I have to increase radius of thumb so mouse curse would turn into a different status (move or ...), currently, it is hard for user to choose or move his cursor super close to those thumbs and requires too much moving and clicking which doesn't make it user friendly.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 0):

Can you just add a Path that is bigger than the object?

For example, you have a circle object with a radius of 10 cm.

Add a circle Path (with transparent color) with a radius of 15.

Comment: Thank you but I found a different way as following, do you think is fine since it sounds like an XAML related issue: Width and Height were 10 so I increased them to 50             `code` <Grid x:Name="RotateThumbs" Opacity="0" Margin="-3">
                            <s:RotateThumb Width="50" 
                             Height="50" `code`